# Error install dms_attachment_link ex OCA v.15 to Odoo 16

Tags: installation, error-handling, odoo-16, dms

I tried to install dms_attachment_link ex. OCA v.15 to Odoo 16, but error:

```
KeyError: ('ir.model.data', <function IrModelData._xmlid_lookup at 0x110a4fac0>,              
'dms.view_dms_file_kanban_wizard_selection')

ValueError: External ID not found in the system: dms.view_dms_file_kanban_wizard_selection

File "/Users/Karunia/odoo16/odoo/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 711, in _tag_root
raise ParseError('while parsing %s:%s, somewhere inside\n%s' % (
odoo.tools.convert.ParseError: while parsing 
/Users/Karunia/odoo16/odoo/addons/dms_attachment_link/views/dms_file_views.xml:3, somewhere 
inside
    <record id="view_dms_file_kanban_wizard_selection" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">dms_file.kanban.wizard.selection.attachment.link</field>
    <field name="model">dms.file</field>
    <field name="priority">9999</field>
    <field name="mode">primary</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="dms.view_dms_file_kanban_wizard_selection"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
    <xpath expr="//div[hasclass('oe_kanban_bottom_right')]" position="inside">
    <a type="object" name="action_create_attachment_from_record" class="btn btn-primary" 
role="button">
                Add
            </a>
        </xpath>
    </field>
</record>
```

I tried to search for solution in stack overflow but still can't find it.